# Huffman golfing

Tags: code-golf, binary-tree

Write a filter that converts text from standard input to a representation of its [Huffman tree](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Huffman_coding) on standard output.  In as few characters as possible.

- you're free to consider newlines or not
- output format is free, as long as it's some *human-readable* encoding of a tree.  s-exps, ascii-art and .png, all good.  RPN, .dot, I'll smile or frown, but that ought to be ok.  Program cores and/or raw pointers , no way.
- no canonicalization needed; if the characters are at the right depth, that's good enough.

Sample possible output for "this is an example of a huffman tree" (from wikipedia):

```
(((e . (n . (o . u))) . (a . (t . m))) .
 (((i . (x . p)) . (h . s)) . (((r . l) . f) . #\space)))
```

I can't reproduce all possible valid outputs with human-readable representation combinations in here (the margin is a bit too thin), but what should check is which characters end up at which number of bits:

- 3 bits: a e [space]
- 4 bits: f h i m n s t
- 5 bits: l o p r u x

If [newline] is kept in, it appears appears in the "5 bits" level, but (any) two characters have to drop from there to 6 bits.

Comment: Why finishing that quick? There're only 2 answers so far.

Comment: No, didn't know that.  Is this written up somewhere?

Comment: I tried it out, but strange enough I could change the accepted answer, even if accepted for half a year. They possibly changed the rules.

Comment: @George Edison: Is this new? I remember this was different before.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### GolfScript, <strike>54</strike> 34 characters

```
:)1/.&.,({{),)@-,-}$(\(@[[\]]+}*~`
```

The script takes input from STDIN and prints the tree in the following form:

```
[[["a" "e"] [["t" "h"] ["i" "s"]]] [[["n" "m"] [["x" "p"] ["l" "o"]]] [[["u" "r"] "f"] " "]]]
```

You may [try the code online](http://golfscript.apphb.com/?c=OyJ0aGlzIGlzIGFuIGV4YW1wbGUgb2YgYSBodWZmbWFuIHRyZWUiCgo6KTEvLiYuLCh7eyksKUAtLC19JChcKEBbW1xdXSt9Kn5g).

*Edit:* In contrast to the longer version the character counts are not saved inside the tree but recalculated each time we need them.

*Previous version with comments:*

```
1/           # split text into chars    
..&          # create string with unique chars

\`{          # for each char
  {1$=},       # filter the original string for this char
  ,            # count number of occurences
  ]            # build data entry [char count]
}+%          # end of for-each loop

.,           # count number of distinct chars
({           # decrement and loop that many times
  {1=}$        # sort list by count field
  (\(@         # take first two elements of sorted list
  +~           # flatten to stack
  [[           # start new entry
    @+           # add count values
    @@[\]        # join nodes into a new tree
    \            # swap count and tree
  ]]+          # close entry and add back to list
}*           # end of for-loop

~~           # flatten array
;            # discard count
`            # transform to readable
```

Answer (score 6):

## Ruby 1.9 - <s>160</s> <s>138</s> 113

```
f=Hash.new(0);$<.chars{|c|f[c]+=1}
f.all?{a,b,*f=f.sort_by(&:last);*a,i=a;*b,j=b;f<<[a,b,i+j];f[1]}
p f[0][0..-2]
```

Ungolfed:

```
f=STDIN.chars.inject(Hash.new(0)){ |f,c|
        f[c]+=1
        f
}
f=f.to_a.map &:reverse

while f.size > 1
        a, b, *f = f.sort_by &:first
        f = [[a[0]+b[0], a, b], *f]
end

p=->a{ a[1].is_a?(String) ? a[1] : [p[a[1]],p[a[2]]] }
p p[f[0]]
```

Output for `this is an example of a huffman tree`:

```
[[[[["l", "p"], ["r", "u"]], ["s", ["o", "x"]]], [["i", "n"], "e"]], [["a", ["h", "t"]], [["m", "f"], " "]]]
```

Answer (score 3):

### Perl, 148

With the `p` command-line option (counted in):

```
$b{$&}++while/./g;for(@_=map[$b{$_},$_],keys%b;$#
_;@_=([$_[0][0]+$_[1][0],"($_[0][1]$_[1][1])"],@_
[2..$#_])){@_=sort{$$a[0]<=>$$b[0]}@_}$_=$_[0][1]
```

Sample use:

```
$ <<< 'this is an example of a huffman tree' perl -pe '$b{$&}++while/./g;for(@_=map[$b{$_},$_],keys%b;$#_;@_=([$_[0][0]+$_[1][0],"($_[0][1]$_[1][1])"],@_[2..$#_])){@_=sort{$$a[0]<=>$$b[0]}@_}$_=$_[0][1]'
(((ae)(((rx)h)((po)(ul))))(((nm)(ti))((sf) )))
```

Ungolfed:

```
# count characters
$b{$&}++ while /./g;

for(
    # init: convert hash to array of [freq,tree] pairs
    @_ = map [$b{$_},$_], keys %b;
    # as long as there are more than one elements left
    $#_;
    # merge the two leftmost nodes
    @_ = ( [ $_[0][0]+$_[1][0], "($_[0][1]$_[1][1])" ], @_[2..$#_] )
)
{
    # keep array in ascending order at all times
    @_=sort{$$a[0]<=>$$b[0]}@_
}

# set up for print
$_=$_[0][1]
```

Answer (score 2):

### Haskell (<s>233</s> <s>228</s> 223)

Not completely shure whether it is valid.

```
import List
data T=Char:=Int|N T T Int
s(x:=_)=show x
s(N a b _)='(':s a++s b++")"
g(_:=a)=a
g(N _ _ a)=a
i[a]=a
i(a:b:x)=t$N a b(g a+g b):x
t=i.sortBy((.g).(compare.g))
main=interact$s.t.map(\x->x!!0:=length x).group.sort
```

Outputs:

- The quick, brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.

```
((((('k''l')('i''j'))(('p''q')('m''n')))((('a''b')('.''T'))(('f''g')('c''d'))))(((('z'('x''y'))'e')((('v''w')('s''t'))'o'))((('r''u')(('\n'',')'h'))' ')))
```

- this is an example of a huffman tree

```
((('a''e')(('h''i')(('o''p')('\n''l'))))((('s''t')('m''n'))((('x'('r''u'))'f')' ')))
```

Output format is like in the question, but whithout whitespace and whithout `,` between the two arms. I assume it's human readable.

Comment: It's perfectly human-readable.  Assuming I'm human.

Comment: http://codepad.org/mjME3TGV - `Program error: pattern match failure: i []`

Comment: @George Edison: you need to provide an input string.  Or alternately: well, that `[]` is a perfectly sensible representation of the empty tree. O:-)

Comment: Adding support for the empty tree would make the whole beast much more complicated.

Answer (score 1):

Python 3.1.2, 132 chars

```
i=input();n=[(i.count(c),c)for c in set(i)]
while n[1:]:n.sort(key=lambda x:x[0]);(a,b),(c,d),*e=n;n=e+[(a+c,(b,d))]
print(n[0][1])
```

It can't handle the empty string.